# Get my own Local DHCP (or static) IP address that is connected to my LAN/Internet

Tags: c#, dns

In C# I wish to get my own DHCP or Static IP address.

I use this code:

```
string host = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);
Console.WriteLine(ip.AddressList[0].ToString());
```

and I get these results:

[image]

How do I know which one to use?  I have virtual PCs installed on this PC as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WMI to access network interface properties  and find out is DHCP is enabled:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcherNetwork = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcherNetwork.Get())
{
    foreach (var prop in queryObj.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} Value: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value));
    }
}
```

Or you can use NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() to get more info such as the Name and NetworkInterfaceType (Ethernet, Wireless80211 etc) and filter by those properties

You can also access IPv4InterfaceProperties.IsDhcpEnabled property such as:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ni.GetIPProperties().GetIPv4Properties().IsDhcpEnabled);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I just want find the IP address of my PC that is connected to my network whether it is static, dhcp or/and on a wireless protocol. This has to work on different pcs that I have no control, knowledge of so I cannot see how that code will help me I am afraid

Comment: I updated the answer and added the bit to access IsDhcpEnabled property. Also with the WMI version you can see there is a property with value "Name: DHCPEnabled Value: True" so it can be used to identify if DHCP is enabled or not

Comment: Hi, sorry for the mid-understanding but it is irrelevant whether it is dhcp or static. I am just saying it could be either

Comment: Your update still does not give me anything to my original posted code. I still get an array of IP addresses. I just need the IP address that is connected to my LAN/internet :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here:

[Get IP Address using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/167ad2/get-ip-address-using-C-Sharp-code/)

This is the code (in case of a broken link. I just did not want to pass this code off as mine you see)

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST
Console.WriteLine(hostName);
// Get the IP
string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
Console.WriteLine("My IP Address is :"+myIP);
```